# Azure Move public IP address to LoadBalancer

Tags: networking, load-balancing, azure

Does anyone know if it is possible to move a public static IP address which currently is associated to a VM/Networkinterface to a LoadBalancer?

Our current server needs to be upscaled and made highavailable. In the current setup the IP address is used for 1 VM. I need to have 2 VM's handling the load, behind the same IP address.

My idea was to use the portal to disassiocate the public IP address from the current network interface, so it would be available to select it for a loadbalancer. But when I choose disassociate it states the IP address will be lost. I really need to avoid that.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Added info:

- This is ARM model
- I dont have problem setting up new VM's, the main objective here is
  to preserve the current public static IP address. This IP address is
  used by a client network with a lot of nodes who all have limited
  internet access. Each accessible IP address for those clients is
  whitelisted in a proxy server (which I don't have access to). So,
  changing the IP address will effectively block those clients to
  connect to the service on a new IP address.

Comment: Does your instance have a Reserved IP Address?

Comment: Is this an ARM or a classic deployment?

Comment: This is a ARM deployment, using public static IP address,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I test in my lab. If you set your Public IP  static assignment. When you dissociate it from VM and associate it to LoadBalancer, the IP address does not change. Please refer to the following steps:

1. Ensure set Public IP static assignment.

[image]

2. Dissociate Public IP from VM.
3. Associate Public IP to LoadBalancer.

Comment: Walter, thanks for the feedback. It did work ... but the warning message was a bit alarming.